# When is it appropriate to farm in the mid-late game?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been having a lot of difficulty lately when playing a carry with being caught out of position when the opposing team goes for Baron, especially when we're behind and I'm trying to either shove a pushed lane, most notably bot, or get the money for an item so I'm actually ready to fight.

Ideally I know I want to be close to Baron's pit when farming, either taking jungle creeps or sticking to mid. But what if such an opportunity doesn't present itself?

So what situation is the ideal time to farm at the point in the game when Baron becomes the focal point?

Am I completely wrong in all of my assumptions so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually during the Mid/Late game both teams are roaming/securing objectives so the only times you really should go for Farm or "Cs" would be when there are no objectives or when there is a large enemy creep wave pushing against your inner towers. If your trying to attain important items before a big fight and the lanes are pushed out, jungle camps are gone or the fight is about to start i recommend just buying wards or potting up (buying the red/blue/green/oracle elixers).

You would also want to push waves out when objectives on the map are coming up like blue/red buffs. Keeping track of their timers would be very useful. For example: You have timed when dragon spawns at 17:58. Your team then pushed out some waves at top/bot/mid at 17:30 and forces one of the enemy team members to defend. You can then easily secure the objective. If the enemy does decide though to confront you it will be a 4v5 situation and you should always mainly come out on top of the situation. If it this is done to your team you would want to send your most mobile/easy wave clear champions to defend these

Timers for objectives:
Starting timers (when they spawn for the first time in the game)
blue/red buffs - 1:50
wolf/wraiths/double golems - 1:40
Baron buff - 15:00

After death timers (time till they spawn again after deaths)
blue/red buffs - 5:00 mins after death
wolf/wraiths/double golems - 50 seconds
Dragon camp - 6mins after death
Baron - 7 mins after death

I hope this was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't just one right answer for that, it depends.

- How is the situaiton in the lanes?
- Are there any missing players? How long has it been since that missing player last seen and where?
- Is dragon up? How much time left if it's not?
- What are the items of the enemy heroes? Are they fed?
- What is the enemy composition? How are they playing? Pushing? Dragging?

I can go on forever.

Generally, you should have some information about the enemy's whereabouts with scouting and wards. And depending on the composition of your team and theirs, you should act as a team with a strategy.

LoL, being a real time strategy game that includes 5 player teams, has so many variables to take into account when deciding the strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Are are many things to consider, but basically it boils down to:

"Could I be doing something better?"

If there isn't anything better to do, then just farm up. But if you're needed for Baron/Dragon, a gank, a teamfight, or to push down a tower, then you should obviously go do that. However, in the absence of anything else to do, farming is never a bad thing to do.

Also, I should point out that you shouldn't be farming as a support during the mid/late game. You should be using your downtime to go place and clear wards.